# With RequireJS how to load files from CDN and local?

Tags: requirejs

In our application the backend passes the base URL of the CDN. So for example:

```
...
<script src="${props.cdn}/jquery.js"></script>
...
<script src="${props.local}/app.js"></script>
...
```

We want to start using RequireJS. So the question is how to pass the the values of ${props.cdn} and ${props.local} to RequireJS and use them there? For example, something like:

```
<script src="${props.cdn}/require.js" data-main="${props.local}/main.js"
  data-cdn="${props.cdn}" data-local="${props.local}"></script>
```

And in the main.js something like:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: require.config.cdn + '/jquery.js',
        someScript: require.config.local + '/someScript.js',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS won't grab anything else than `data-main` from your `script` tag. One way to get what you want would be to do this:

```
<script>
    require = {
        paths: {
            jquery: '${props.cdn}/jquery.js',
            someScript: '${props.local}/someScript.js',
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="${props.cdn}/require.js" data-main="${props.local}/main.js"/>
```

The way RequireJS works, if you set `require` to a RequireJS configuration before loading RequireJS, then RequireJS will pick up its initial configuration there. You can still have a call to `require.config` in your `main.js` file that adds shims and paths. RequireJS combines multiple configurations into a single one.

Another way to do this would be to use the `config` configuration option but you'd have to structure your code quite a bit differently from what you have now.